# Does there exist a likelihood based experimental methodology book on undergraduate level for psychology / social science students?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, references

I've been looking for an introductory book in statistics and experiment design for a methods course for psychology students. I think I've been looking through at least 30 books and all go through the same old motions. Fist hypothesis testing, then t-test, Anova, two-Way Anova and ordinary least square regression. And all of them insist on explaining these models by tedious calculations. A t-test requires you to calculate a t-statistic, an Anova requires you to sum squares of this and that, regression instead is done my minimizing the squared error.

From my perspective I find it *much* easier and intuitive to understand these types of models from a likelihood perspective. For example, a t-test is the model $y \sim \text{Normal}(\beta_0 + \beta_1x,\sigma^2)$ and an Anova is $y \sim \text{Normal}(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 +  \ldots,\sigma^2)$  where $x, x_1, x_2$ are dummy coded variables. To fit such a model one would then use, for example, maximum likelihood which  I find intuitive and easy to explain. This kind formulation also makes the connection between a t-test, an ANOVA and regression trivial to understand.

So what I've been looking for an introductory book in statistics and experiment design that teaches statistics from this likelihood perspective. I would be very grateful for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

James K. Lindsey has several books in similar vein. Perhaps the one nearest to your goal is

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Applied-Statistics-Modelling-Approach/dp/0198528957/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not quite what you have in mind, but Dan Navarro has written a textbook for his own undergraduate statistics subject in psychology. I have read it all, but it seems to use the approach you mention on occasion. It uses a fair bit of R and generally seems to be more sophisticated than your average intro psych stats textbook. The PDF of the chapters are available online for free.

Daniel Navarro: [Learning Statistics with R](http://health.adelaide.edu.au/psychology/ccs/teaching/lsr/)